# is Windows Vista x64 Ultimate secure with replaced shell explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-vista, security, shell, operating-systems, internet-security

I've replaced explorer.exe as the default shell with steam.exe using a program called instant sheller. I don't want to run the stock firewall, and want to invoke the firewall and antivirus from the directories they are installed from to monitor them.

Will my OS get updates like a regular install of windows, and would the system be secure?

EDIT: Windows Vista updated and restarted automatically without user intervention - so that part is answered. The security side of the question still is an issue though.

add: yes, I want to know if it will be secure without running antivirus and firewall manually. And will it be secure if I run them manually.

Comment: and what if I replace it with EventGhost application - eventghost.org

Comment: Maybe flag this post. Someone can flag?

Comment: You really need to **rewrite** (edit) this question. It's very hard to understand what you want.

Comment: is it edited ok now?

Comment: @Saulius - No.  Its not clear.  You need to install Security Software, You need to Install Patches, replacing the shell with Steam is a very bad idea.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I saw yesterday that windows vista was updated and restarted automatically as I was looking at Steam GUI. Without the user touching a PC

Comment: I've streamlined the question dramatically and hopefully cleared it up.You may need to change minor details, since the original question *was* a bit of a ramble.

Comment: now I posted update. I think the question is clear now. Is it?

Comment: Edited. Take notes! Additional information goes below the question proper

Comment: yes, I want to know if it will be secure without running antivirus and firewall manually. And will it be secure if I run them manually.

Comment: @Saulius - No, it won't be secure, you should have passive security running ALL the time.  A on demand firewall is useless, on demand anti-virus is useless, not running updates WHEN they are released makes your system not secure.  Furthermore updates to applications should be installed right away.

Comment: Vista was updated automatically yesterday without running explorer shell

Answer (score 4):

There's no real guarantee of security. I'll cover *some* issues and ideas, both on how to do this, and where you need to be careful about.

I notice you've missed out whether you're running the system as admin or a regular user. I could live with a system without persistant AV or Firewall *as a regular user*, since it would be much harder to compromise such a system (windows vista and 7 do this by default anyway with UAC. A user who *can't* elevate himself is even better though).

It'd also depend on your overall setup - you could offload firewall (and even AV) duties to a firewall.

Running a system like this, you need to be aware of *why* you are doing this, what your threat profile is, and what your risk factors are.

Most people running a stripped down system do this in an attempt to improve system performance - are you actually bottlenecked? Does 'Ricing' out your system by stripping out AV and Firewall actually make a difference? Could you, alternately simply use a lighter AV or set it to a more frugal setting while gaming? If you need to turn off AV, shell and firewall for decent performance, you might do well to consider upgrading your system, or switching your OS to windows xp or maybe 7.

Persistant AV and Firewalls don't just clean your system, they delete things *as* they come in - to the point where my AV kept deleting elcar test files i was making *as i saved them*. Its a much better solution than on demand scans. Sometimes its better to have a shield, thana sword.

Could you restrict yourself to only steam servers at your firewall? Can you lock down your system effectively? Do you have the tools and skills in place to find and deal with a system compromise?

In short, its a bad idea *unless* you know exactly what you're doing. There's very little that suggests turning off things like explorer to run just steam does any good. If you *must* set up one regular user account that way, and run a admin account with AV and firewall.

Comment: so if I start my purchased firewall manually, and also purchased antivirus it will be secure? That part I still don't understand

Comment: Vista was updated automatically yesterday without running explorer shell

Comment: From the point of time you start them, assuming the system hasn't already been compromised by something that would hide from the AV (like a rootkit) or would actively subvert it, or prevent it from running, *maybe*.Thats a very uncertain maybe. I left out updates in my answer since you found out it happens anyway. You are MUCH better off letting the firewall and AV run automatically

Comment: how can I test my OS security running like that?

Comment: Thats a whole different subject on its own. I just tend to test stuff with an [eicar file](http://eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html). On the other hand, i have AV and firewall by default, with a second firewall at the router. I am a firm believer in defence in depth.

Comment: what about real shell replacement that is available to download on the web. Is it secure? Is there any real shell replacement for gaming to buy?

Comment: I thought I will test my OS security online

Comment: Most of them run on top of explorer. They're just graphical tweaks. I just run stock systems since i don't have to stay awake at night wandering about these things. Seriously, my advice is don't bother.Just run the system as is, the extra TINY bit of performance you'll get isn't worth it. At worst, run windows classic.

I'd also note, i've put a heck of a lot more effort into this question/answer than usual. I don't mind if the community deletes it, but i'd be slightly miffed it the original poster deleted it.

Comment: Running a 'stripped down version' of Windows like this won't make you 'immune' from viruses and as JG has said, unless you know what you're doing it is very dangerous to run without on-access AV and passive firewall. As you have already found out, stopping the shell doesn't stop windows update - the same is true for many other things, especially AV/Firewall. 'Running the .exe' isn't enough to run the program, it has certain dependancies and modules which would be loaded first (usually as system services).

Comment: As you just want to run Steam and i'm assuming you'll not be using the PC for web browsing/downloading and e-mail. If that is the case then you **could** get away without running an AV on-access scanner and no firewall... Providing you have a hardware firewall on your router, you could then add 'safe application' rules (in the AV) for your games and the required ports on your firewall. You still won't gain much performance from doing this, but you will be at least slightly more secure than running AV+Firewall ad-hoc.

Comment: thanks for this ('Running the .exe' isn't enough to run the program) I now understand